# Silverlight callback mystery behavior

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, event-handling, navigation

I am writting this method to track if changes occured on a page so the user can trigger a reload of a dependent system. So this as you can see triggers when the user is trying to navigate away from the page. If the e.Cancel is not there the behavior seems fine the async web-service call happen as expected but I am not sure what is really happening in the back.

The reload button click method triggers a chain of event that usually update the display but since the user has navigated away from the page the components are no longer visible. Can this cause problems to the application? Should I be forcing the user to remain on the same page just to prevent possible callback problems?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        if (hasDataBeenModified)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("You have not reloaded the policies\nDo you want to do it now?"))
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                ReloadButton_Click(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding the OnBackKeyPress method, if you're concerned about them backing out of the page.

Comment: Are you saying that when I hit the back button my previous state of the page is restored ? So when i hit back i do not run the constructor again?

Comment: You can override the OnBackkeyPress method and if you cancel at that time nothing on the page will have changed, the page itself is still there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using OnNavigatingFrom, use OnBackKeyPress

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (hasDataBeenModified)
    {
        if (System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("You have not reloaded the policies\nDo you want to do it now?"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            ReloadButton_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```